# Как заспавнить игрока в определенную точку при переходе на другую сцену(уровень)

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня не работает скрипт. Нужно, чтобы когда игрок вышел из дома, он переходит на другую сцену именно ВОЗЛЕ ДВЕРИ, (откуда вышел тип). Но при переходе он у меня появляется в начальной точке спавна (откуда начинается игра, и это далеко от самого дома). Написал скрипт, чтобы игрок появился именно в том месте, но не помогло. Консоль показывает, что ошибок нет.
версия unity 2019.4.3
скрипт :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class exithouse : MonoBehaviour
{
   public string LevelName;
   
   private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
   {
       if (other.tag == "Player")
       {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(LevelName);
            transform.position = new Vector3(-18.47f,-0.074609f,-31.3068f);
       }
   }
}
```

[image: объект, на который закинут скрипт]
[image: координаты игрока, стоящего возле выхода из дома]

1. **объект, на который закинут скрипт**
2. **координаты игрока, стоящего на выходе из дома**

Comment: Если один из ответов вам помог, не забудьте его отметить как принятый, галочка слева от ответа

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы через transform.position переносите  Cylinder, а не Player. Попробуйте сделать так:

```
...

public class exithouse : MonoBehaviour
{
   public string LevelName;
   public Vector3 positionPlayer;
   
   private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
   {
       if (other.tag == "Player")
       {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(LevelName);
            positionPlayer  = new Vector3(-18.47f,-0.074609f,-31.3068f);
       }
   }
}
```

В новой сцене:

```
...

public class SetPlayerPosition : MonoBehaviour
{
   public GameOdject Player;
   public exithouse eh;
   
   void Start()
   {
       Player.transform.position = eh.positionPlayer;
   }
}
```

Вообще, по хорошему можно через SceneManager проверить какая сцена активна в данный момент(просто повесить на пустой объект в новой сцене):

```
...

public class managerscene : MonoBehaviour
{
   public string LevelName;
   public GameOdject Player;
   
   void Start()
   {
       Scene currentScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();

       string SceneName = currentScene.name;

       if (SceneName == "Имя вашей сцены")
       {
            Player.transform.position = new Vector3(-18.47f,-0.074609f,-31.3068f);
       }
   }
}
```

скрипт, запускающий сцену:

```
...

public class exithouse : MonoBehaviour
{
   public string LevelName;
   

   private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
   {
       if (other.tag == "Player")
       {
           SceneManager.LoadScene(LevelName);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, сейчас попробую!!!

Comment: @андрей всё работает или ещё остались какие-либо вопросы?

Comment: все получилось :))

Answer (score 0):

Игрок не перемещается, потому что вы не в тот момент меняете его позицию. Вообще, можно на второй сцене сразу игрока поставить в нужную позицию. Она должна сохраниться. Если нужно именно через код поменять позицию, то лучше сделать так:

```
//Создайте объект на второй сцене, в которой нужно заспаунить игрока,
// и накиньте на объект этот скрипт
public class PlayerSpawner : Monobehaviour
{
   //Сюда нужно прокинуть объект игрока
   [SerializeField] private GameObject _player; 

   // здесь ваша позиция для спауна
   private readonly Vector3 _spawnPosition = new Vector3(-18.47f,-0.074609f,-31.3068f);

   //этот метод автоматически вызовется, когда новая сцена загрузится
   private void Awake()
   {
      //Меняем позицию игрока
     _player.transform.position = _spawnPosition;
   }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное!!!!